# PHP Algorithm to group items in an array so that the sum of group equals numbers divisible by 8

Tags: php, algorithm

I've been working on this problem for a while now, and I'm just not sure how to solve it.  My array looks like this, but I'm willing to re-format things if it makes it easier to solve:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => ff
        [number_bits] => 10
        [description] => asdf
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => hh
        [number_bits] => 5
        [description] => asdf
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => dd
        [number_bits] => 4
        [description] => asdf
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => ee
        [number_bits] => 4
        [description] => asfd
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => gg
        [number_bits] => 4
        [description] => asdf
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => bb
        [number_bits] => 2
        [description] => asdf
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => aa
        [number_bits] => 1
        [description] => asdf
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => cc
        [number_bits] => 1
        [description] => sdaf
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => ii
        [number_bits] => 1
        [description] => asdf
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => jj
        [number_bits] => 1
        [description] => afsd
    )

)
```

What I need to do is group these items together so that the 'number_bits' add up to a number divisible by 8.  For example, by looking at these I can see that ff, hh, & aa could be grouped together because the number_bits for each add up to 16.  Also, dd and ee could be grouped together as they add up to 8.  I don't anticipate needed to go beyond groups that add up to 24, if that makes it easier.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: That is not an `php` question. Its a real `algorithm` question. So better post it directly under https://stackexchange.com/filters/105  (you Q is in the list there) What language is used to do the math is not so relevant and i thing you looking for an algorithm that reduces complexty to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, both of you.  I keep that all in mind when I post again.  I have actually spent quite a number of hours trying to write code that will handle this situation, but what I've come up with is way to long and messy to post here.

Comment: Maybe the most simple(and worst from the perspective of performance) would be a brute force method. You try to pair each element with each other element, and you do it as far as the sum is divisible with 8.